# How can I Solve $y^{\prime\prime}+\frac2{x}y^{\prime}+y^3=0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The equation below is a non-linear second order differential equation. $$y^{\prime\prime}+\dfrac{2}{x}y^{\prime}+y^3=0$$
I don't know how can I solve it?
Would somebody help me?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?  How did you come across it?  Do you have any reason to believe that this differential equation should have a closed-form solution?

Comment: No, I just saw it on the net and tried to solve it, but I couldn't. My main area is Commutative algebra, just for a review of differential equations I wanted to solve this problem.
I wanted to learn more in other areas.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: It doesn't look like this differential equation has a closed form solution.  After some googling, it seems that this is an example of an [Emden Fowler DE](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Emden-FowlerDifferentialEquation.html), if that helps

Comment: Thank you very much, my friend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $u=xy$ ,

Then $\dfrac{du}{dx}=x\dfrac{dy}{dx}+y$

$\dfrac{d^2u}{dx^2}=x\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\dfrac{dy}{dx}+\dfrac{dy}{dx}=x\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}+2\dfrac{dy}{dx}$

$\therefore\dfrac{1}{x}\dfrac{d^2u}{dx^2}+\dfrac{u^3}{x^3}=0$

$\dfrac{d^2u}{dx^2}=-\dfrac{u^3}{x^2}$

This belongs to a special case of Emden-Fowler equation.

Comment: Thank you my friend.